# Character Mesh Distorts Upon Keyframing

Tags: animation, mesh, distort

[image: Before adding any keyframes]

[image: After keyframing]

Hello there. I've been following tutorials online to be able to model and rig a character to animate it. The essential animation has been done and my character actually looks like he walks normally. What I've been trying to do is make him move across the screen in the x axis; just a simple walk across the frame. So I go to frame one and put my mouse over the meshes object X location and press "I" to enter a key frame, and then I do the same at the end after moving the character across the screen, but as soon as I do that, my mesh distorts and "conbobulates" into a weird shape leaving the bones aside while barely moving across the screen. I can't seem to find any help for this specifically. Any help would be appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: true answer for your problem is point 2

**1)**

If you want to move your character along the X axis for example, you need to move the armature (in Object mode), not the object itself: The object is parented to the armature, so it will follow the armature. So delete the keyframes you've created for the object and create keyframes for the armature.

To see the keyframes of the selected object only, enable this button on the bottom of the Dopesheet window, otherwise you'll see all the keyframes of all the objects of your scene.

Now select the character object (not the armature) and delete the keyframes you've probably created.

[image]

**2)**

Now, my first answer didn't fix your problem but I've found the anomaly. I can't explain how it happened but this will fix the problem: Go into the Outliner, you'll see that the Animation is part of the object while it should not be the case, so *ctrl right click* over Animation and *Clear Animation Data*

[image]

Comment: But regardless if I click on the mesh alone, or the bones alone, or both the mesh and the bone with shift right click, the walking key frames are the same. If I just click the mesh (object) and I delete those keyframes, its basically erasing the ones from the armature. When I move the character around in x value, he doesn't distort. Its only when I insert the first keyframe that the entire distortion occurs.

Comment: I've edited my answer, does it answer your question?

Comment: I really appreciate you helping me out but I just followed what you said and the problem still persist. I recorded the issue from my phone to better explain and so that you can further see  my setup https://youtu.be/uhSo-Ovw7PA

Comment: could you please share your file (the bugged version)

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5040" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5040/)

Comment: Any help resolving this is greatly appreciated

Comment: Ok I've found out, I'm going to edit my post

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't express what a relief this is. I'm still very curious as to how that happened so I can avoid it in the future, but it very much did solve my problem. Thank you. :)